# Perform sum of vectors in CUDA/thrust

Tags: vector, cuda, thrust, gradient-descent

So I'm trying to implement stochastic gradient descent in CUDA, and my idea is to parallelize it similar to the way that is described in the paper [Optimal Distributed Online Prediction Using Mini-Batches](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.1367.pdf)

That implementation is aimed at MapReduce distributed environments so I'm not sure if it's optimal when using GPUs.

In short the idea is: at each iteration, calculate the error gradients for each data point in a batch (map), take their average by sum/reducing the gradients, and finally perform the gradient step updating the weights according to the average gradient. The next iteration starts with the updated weights.

The [thrust](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/) library allows me to perform a reduction on a vector allowing me for example to sum all the elements in a vector.

My question is: How can I sum/reduce an array of vectors in CUDA/thrust?
The input would be an array of vectors and the output would be a vector that is the sum of all the vectors in the array (or, ideally, their average).

Comment: an "array of vectors" is the same as a matrix (if the vector lengths are equal); have a look at the [`sum_rows`](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/sum_rows.cu) example which show how to sum the rows of a matrix

Comment: Thrust is designed to work on [POD types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c), so the really short answer is that you probably can't do this using Thrust without changing the storage format of you data

Comment: @m.s. Thanks, I think a construct like this can solve my problem.

Comment: @m.s if you want to provide an answer, I would upvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Converting my comment into this answer:*

Let's say each vector has length `m` and the array has size `n`. 
An "array of vectors" is then the same as a matrix of size `n x m`.

If you change your storage format from this "array of vectors" to a single vector of size `n * m`, you can use `thrust::reduce_by_key` to sum each row of this matrix separately.

The [`sum_rows`](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/sum_rows.cu) example shows how to do this.